# xamarin forms label font attributes is not working properly in navigatonbar. i am using navigationbar.settitleview() can anyone help me out?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i created label with csharp. after that i added to stacklayout. it is displaying text prperly with alignments and size. but it is not working font attibutes property.

```
Label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic
```

Comment: Label view = new Label
        {
            Text = "Hello",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start,
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic
        };
this is entire code

Comment: have you included a font-awesome asset?

Comment: I think you have to add Italic Font Family in your application.

Answer (score 2):

I just test with the latest version(4.7.0.968) of Xamarin.forms and your code works well:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Label view = new Label { 
            Text = "Hello", 
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)), 
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, 
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand, 
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, 
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation, 
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic 
        };

        Content = view;
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image: screenShot]

NavigationBar titleView:

[image]

Comment: can you try with that in navigation bar. actually i was doing that in NavigationPage.setTitleView()

Comment: thanks for the effort. and yes it looks fine. but i created sample project. in that for me also working as expected. but not working in my real project. i will find the cause of that. thanks a lot

Comment: You can share some relevant code of your real project here and we can check it for you. Also, you can mark this answer if it helps you.

Comment: @Vijay did you find any solution for this issue on android?